C++ Unexpected behaviour in floating-point operation
So, I writed some code:
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main() {

    int a,b,n;
    std::cin >> a >> b >> n;
    double xi[n];
    double yi[n];
    double h = (b - a + 0.0) / n + 0.0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i) { //filling the arrays
        xi[i] = a + (h*i);
        yi[i] = xi[i]*xi[i]*std::acos(0.9*xi[i]); //the 
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; ++i)  { //displaying first 5 elements of the arrays
        std::cout << "x" << i << ": " << xi[i] << "\n";
        std::cout << "y" << i << ": " << yi[i] << "\n\n";
    }
    return 0;
}

If you try to run it with a = 0, b = 1 and n = 10 (later I discovered that any number divisible by 10 gives similar results), then instead of x0 = 0, you will see that x0 = 0.451027.
I tried forcefully assigning to xi[0] its supposed value
if (i == 0) {
    xi[i] = a;
}

Now x0 still equals to this 0.451027 nonsense, but if in the first case the value of y0 was correct (0), with forced assigning it is 9.2684e-315, which is almost correct if you think, but still is not 0. static_cast was also helpless in solving this mystery.
It feels surreal and yet it happens run after run. Is it possible to fix it?

for (int i = 0; i <= n;...   Arrays in C++ have valid indexes 0 .. n-1.   xi[i]  when i == n is indexing out of bounds.

C++ doesn't have variable length arrays. Use std::vector instead.

If you change that <= to <, or allocate your xi and yi arrays to have size n+1, you'll get results closer to what you expect.

what is x0, do you mean xi[0]? <O/T>, + 0.0 is useless.

But why does it happen only when n is divisible by 10?

@h-swell because of undefined behavior. It's not worth reasoning around why specific things happen in UB land, unless you're writing or debugging a compiler.

@h-swell don't try to identify patterns in a program with undefined behavior. The compiler is allowed to optimise it in quite unexpected ways. Fix your program first

Tried your code, I get nothing happening after the input. Exchanged your illegal arrays for std::vector and it suddenly worked, even despite the bad for loop. Most likely everything worked for you before due to UB, with some underlying structures happening to have good sizes by chance, but maybe overlapped when initialized with a multiple of ten. That's UB for you.

@h-swell When you declare an array of size 10, and write 11 values to it, you typically overwrite some memory somewhere outside of the array, with generally unpredictable results.

To clarify the point about everyone saying "don't use VLAs (variable length arrays)" -- VLAs are fine if your compiler has an extension allowing VLAs. Most compilers that you're going to be learning C++ on will allow this just fine. Keep in mind that they're not technically supported by the C++ standard, so there are some compilers out there that won't accept them.

@steve-summit Don't I overwrite some memory outside of the array declaring an array of size 11 and writing 12 values to it?

why does it happen only when n is divisible by 10? Sometimes you can learn something interesting from questions like this.  Not this time, though.  In this case, it's like asking "I took the wheel off my car to work on the brakes, and when I put the wheel back on, I forgot to tighten the bolts, and the next day, when I was driving 60 mph, the wheel flew off and the car went into the ditch.  So I put the wheel back on, and I forgot to tighten the bolts again, and the next time I drove, when the wheel flew off, the car veered into the other lane and I ran head-on into a semi.  Why different?

@h-swell If n is 10, and you declare int xi[n];, you get an array xi with 10 elements, not 11.  (Those 10 elements have indices that run from 0 to 9.)

@h-swell Seriously, who here do you feel is harassing you?

@h-swell it's not possible to reason about Undefined Behaviour (UB).  All you can do is remove any UB from the code that you find and try again.  Maybe there are other problems we haven't yet spotted, but trying to find them in the presence of UB is pointless. Please fix the UB and test again, if the code still has problems please post a new question.

If you are writing standard C++, don't use VLAs.  If you are writing C++ with some compiler specific extensions, then you are not writing standard C++.  C++ provides for dynamic arrays, std::vector.

@h-swell If you thought my analogy involving car wheels was insulting, I'm sorry.  Many beginners imagine that as long as a program compiles without error, it will do something predictable, according to sensible rules.  But when it comes to undefined behavior, that's not so. But this can be a tricky point to get across, so we often resort to extreme analogies like the one about the car wheel.  There are reasons which explain why you saw what you saw with multiples of 10, but the reasons are just about as random and irrelevant as the factors that cause different kinds of car crashes.

Array bounds: your loop for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i) is going to cause you all sorts of trouble because you're accessing out of bounds on xi and yi. arrays in c++ are zero-indexed, so you should loop from 0 to n-1. Like this: for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i).
This fixes the issue.

Thank you! That did really help. But why does it happen only when n is divisible by 10?

@h-swell because of some combination of optimizations that the compiler is running. To really get that answer you'll have to be very familiar with the compiler's source code or have a free weekend to comb through it. It's unlikely that anyone here will be interested in doing that for you for UB. Not worth our time or interest. In the next version of the compiler it might work just fine for values divisible by 10 but not divisible by 16. Who's to say.

I think, that when you try to acces that 11th, 21st, 31st... place in the array it somehow loops around and changes the 1st value instead, if you print more values, you can see the 11th y - (y10) has the same value as the x0 - 0.451027.
